# Beautiful Soup Using Regex to Find Tags?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I'd really like to be able to allow Beautiful Soup to match any list of tags, like so. I know attr accepts regex, but is there anything in beautiful soup that allows you to do so?

```
soup.findAll("(a|div)")
```

Output:

```
<a> ASDFS
<div> asdfasdf
<a> asdfsdf
```

My goal is to create a scraper that can grab tables from sites. Sometimes tags are named inconsistently, and I'd like to be able to input a list of tags to name the 'data' part of a table.

Comment: you can use a list of tags: `soup.find_all(['a', 'div'])`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is the most favored method in the Beautiful Soup search API.

You can pass a variation of filters. Also, pass a [list](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-list) to find multiple tags:

```
>>> soup.find_all(['a', 'div'])
```

**Example**:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><body><div>asdfasdf</div><p><a>foo</a></p></body></html>')
>>> soup.find_all(['a', 'div'])
[<div>asdfasdf</div>, <a>foo</a>]
```

Or you can use a [regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) to find tags that contain `a` or `div`:

```
>>> import re
>>> soup.find_all(re.compile("(a|div)"))
```

Answer (score 92):

Note that you can also use regular expressions to **search in attributes of tags**. For example:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup.find_all('a', {'href': re.compile(r'crummy\.com/')})
```

This example finds all `<a>` tags that link to a website containing the substring `'crummy.com'`.

Answer (score 7):

yes see docs...

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html

```
import re

soup.findAll(re.compile("^a$|(div)"))
```

Comment: see point #2 here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#arg-name 
`You can also pass in a regular expression. This code finds all the tags whose names start with B:`