# Extract data from <script> with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some data with Python and Beautifulsoup. I know how to get the text from the script tag. The data between [ ] is valid json.

```
<script>
    dataLayer = 
[  
  {  
  "p":{  
         "t":"text1",
         "lng":"text2",
         "vurl":"text3"
       },
  "c":{  },
  "u":{  },
  "d":{  },
  "a":{  }
  }
]
</script>
```

I've read this response and it almost does what I want:
[Extract content of <Script with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192727/extract-content-of-script-with-beautifulsoup)

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = "www.example.com"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
raw_data = soup.find("script")
```

I would then ideally do:

```
json_dict = json.loads(raw_data)
```

And access the data through the dictionary. But this is not working because of

```
"<script> dataLayer ="
```

preceding the valid json and the script tag at the end. I've tried trimming the raw_data as a string, like this:

```
raw_data[20:]
```

But this didn't work because the soup object is not a string.

How can I get the raw_data variable to contain ONLY the text between the block quotes [ ]?

EDIT: this seems to work. It avoids regex and solves the problem of the trailing chars as well. Thanks for your suggestions.

```
url = "www.example.com"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# get the script tag data and convert soup into a string
data = str(soup.find("script"))

# cut the <script> tag and some other things from the beginning and end to get valid JSON
cut = data[27:-13]

# load the data as a json dictionary
jsoned = json.loads(cut)
```

Comment: Can you provide the URL?

Comment: We need to know which script tag this is in to provide an accurate result.

Answer (score 1):

use `.text` to get content inside `<script>` tag then replace `dataLayer =`

```
raw_data = soup.find("script")
raw_data = raw_data.text.replace('dataLayer =', '')
json_dict = json.loads(raw_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> soup.find_all(re.compile("\[(.*?)\]"))
```

you would do that with [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

You will have to create a regex norm that only takes text between []

[here a link of common regex usage within beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748445/beautiful-soup-using-regex-to-find-tags)

[here the regex to extract from between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working. re_soup = soup.find_all(re.compile("\[(.*?)\]")) and then: data = json.loads(re_soup) and then: print(data) gives a "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not ResultSet"

Comment: first of all your regex is wrong, u forgot to escape square brackets

Comment: also this is a plus but use pprint instead of print