# How to extract text based on a condition in python

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have my soup data like below.

```
<a href="/title/tt0110912/" title="Quentin Tarantino">
Pulp Fiction
</a>

<a href="/title/tt0137523/" title="David Fincher">
Fight Club
</a>

<a href="blablabla" title="Yet to Release">
Yet to Release
</a>

<a href="something" title="Movies">
Coming soon
</a>
```

I need the text data from those `a` tags on a condition, maybe `href=/title/*wildcharacter*`

My could somewhat looks like this.

```
titles = []

for a in soup.find_all("a",href=True):
    if a.text:
        titles.append(a.text.replace('\n'," "))
print(titles)
```

But with this condition, i get texts from all the `a` tags. I need only texts where `href` has `"/title/***"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want it like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="/title/tt0110912/" title="Quentin Tarantino">
Pulp Fiction
</a>

<a href="/title/tt0137523/" title="David Fincher">
Fight Club
</a>

<a href="blablabla" title="Yet to Release">
Yet to Release
</a>

<a href="something" title="Movies">
Coming soon
</a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

titles = []

for a in soup.select('a[href*="/title/"]',href=True):
    if a.text:
        titles.append(a.text.replace('\n'," "))
print(titles)
```

Output:

```
[' Pulp Fiction ', ' Fight Club ']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to search for the contents of an attribute (in this case href).

For more details please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47091570/1426630

Answer (score 0):

1.) To get all `<a>` tags, where the `href=` begins with `"/title/"`, you can use CSS selector `a[href^="/title/"]`.

2.) To strip all text inside the tag, you can use `.get_text()` with parameter `strip=True`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

out = [a.get_text(strip=True) for a in soup.select('a[href^="/title/"]')]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['Pulp Fiction', 'Fight Club']
```