# How to standardize HTML tags and then use them in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a **scraper** in Python. I have a problem because some tags look like this:

```
<span class='review pos'>Text...</span>
```

And I collect them like this:

```
soup.findAll("span", {"class": "review pos"})
```

And some of it looks like this.

```
<span class='review neg'>Text...</span>
```

Before collecting content between tags, I would like to standardize them first so that they always look like this.

```
<span class='review'>Text...</span>
```

My code look like:

```
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

# <==  at this point I would like to unify all tags 

review_positive_and_negative = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "review pos"})
```

Comment: `soup.find_all(re.compile("^review"))`, [`see here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24748491/4985099)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case, there are two classes inside those `<div>`s (`'review'` and `'pos'`).
So one method of finding the tags is by searching only based off the `review` class.

```py
divs = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'review'})
```

This works in this context, but if you had classes that looked like `review-pos` or `review-neg`, those would count only as one class. In this case, the easiest way to find those tags would by searching using [RegEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

```py
import re
divs = soup.findAll('div', {'class': re.compile('^review-.*')})

# This matches all the `div` tags that have the class:
#  * Start (^) with "review-"
#  * Followed by any number of characters (.*)
```

For more information about RegEx check this [quick guide](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html).

Comment: However, your solution is the best thanothers because it keeps the original order. Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 2):

You can use extend for each search all because the result from **search_all** is list of ***<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>*** that you use method extend:

```
# filename: scraper.py

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<span class='review pos'>Text.</span>
<span class='review neg'>Text...</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

review_positive_and_negative = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "review pos"})
review_positive_and_negative.extend(soup.findAll("span", {"class": "review neg"}))


for row in review_positive_and_negative:
    print(row.string)
```

Example output:

```
$ python scraper.py
   Text.
   Text...
```

Comment: I've been tested with this answer, and it is working well, thanks

Comment: Tank you very much. This is what I meant! In line:  {"class": "review neg"})  an ending bracket is missing     :)