# Unable to target different `h` tags using css selector without knowing their variation

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When there are classes like `listing__name_123` or `listing__name_789`, I can select both of them using `soup.slect_one("[class^='listing__name_']")`.

However, when there are tags like `h1`,`h5`, `h7`, `h13`, I don't find any way to select them the same way I selected different classes. I know I can use `soup.slect_one("h1,h5,h7,h13")` to target them but the problem is I may not be aware of the variety of `h` tags in advance.

Example tags:

```
<h1>A Complexity Profile</h1>
<h5>INDIVIDUAL AND COLLECTIVE BEHAVIOR</h5>
<h7>MESSY PROFILE</h7>
<h13>Conclusion</h13>
```

Current attempt:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml") #html contains the desired h tags
soup.select_one("h1,h5,h7,h13")
```

> How can I target all the `h` tags using css selector without knowing their variation?

Comment: Is `<h7>` and greater a thing? I thought they only went to 6. You could probably [use a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748445/beautiful-soup-using-regex-to-find-tags): `soup.find_all(re.compile("^h\d+$"))`

Comment: Consider those `h` tags as placeholders. I suppose you understood what my question is up to @ggorlen? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you need, actually. `h` tags are placeholders for what?

Comment: Placeholders for any tag which are less than <h7>.

Comment: It seems like you already have it: `soup.select_one("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6")`... right? (or `select` without `_one` if you want all of them)

Comment: I'd really recommend using only standard HTML tags. HTML structure is very important for a good Google Score see https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data