# In python, how would I select a HTML node with a changing ID number

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a webscraper to scrape the data of user profiles from a specific website, using Python, BS4, Selenium. I'm trying to scrape data from a particular section of the site - the particular sections node has no unique identifying features from other section nodes, other than an ID number preceded by the word 'ember', like so:

```
<section id="ember31" class="artdeco-card ember-view pv-top-card">
```

The section ID can be "ember" followed by two OR three numbers - these numbers randomise everytime the page is loaded. There are multiple of these throughout the page - but I only wish to select one.

This is fine for scraping one profile, but how would I ensure that my code selects the correct node each time it runs through a new profile?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you add a snippet of code showing what you've tried so far?

Comment: It sounds like a regular expression search inside of BeautifulSoup might solve your problem. Check this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748445/beautiful-soup-using-regex-to-find-tags

Comment: Use XPath with [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) or pass regular expression or pass lambda to method of beautiful soup you're using which will check substring.

Comment: @SNygard - Thanks! If I'm able to find the node, how would I then be able to select the child node, the child node of that child node and then iterate through the subsequent list items?

Comment: @MOK_Z, that gets into a separate question. But in general, you can search within the child nodes in the same way you search the parent `soup` object. For example `node = soup.find(<filter>)` (using your filter from before), then `node.find(<new_filter)` inside of that.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is *id starts with ember* and you use `BeautifulSoup` try the `css selectors`:

```
soup.select_one('[id^=ember].artdeco-card.ember-view.pv-top-card')
```

###### Example

Used `select` instead of `select_one` for demonstration, that it only select the specific one.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<section id="ember31" class="artdeco-card ember-view pv-top-card">section #1</section>
<section id="ember4711" class="something else">section #2</section>
<section id="embar123" class="artdeco-card ember-view pv-top-card">section #3</section>
<section id="notember123" class="artdeco-card ember-view pv-top-card">section #4</section>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.select('[id^=ember].artdeco-card.ember-view.pv-top-card')
```

###### Output

```
[<section class="artdeco-card ember-view pv-top-card" id="ember31">section #1</section>]
```

Comment: This would be correct if there were other unique identifying features in the node. However, unfortunately, the class is exactly the same throughout. 

It's more like:

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<section id="ember31" class="artdeco-card ember-view pv-top-card">section #1</section>
<section id="ember471" class="artdeco-card ember-view pv-top-card">section #2</section>
<section id="ember123" class="artdeco-card ember-view pv-top-card">section #3</section>
<section id="ember234" class="artdeco-card ember-view pv-top-card">section #4</section>
'''`

Comment: Would be great if you could provide some more details (HTML, url, written code) in your question to clarify. thanks